# The Key Error : logtostderr (python, tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, python-3.6

I am trying to implement a InceptionV3 to classify the images.
(python 3.65 / tensorflow 1.14.0)

when I run the code, I am getting these key error : "logtostderr".
I don't know why this Key error happens.

How can I solve this problem?

Last week, I ran this code smoothly.
but, the problem was happened yesterday suddenly.

```
with tf.train.MonitoredSession(session_creator=session_creator) as sess:    
        for filenames, images in load_images(FLAGS.input_dir, batch_shape):
            labels = sess.run(predicted_labels, feed_dict={x_input: images})
            for filename, label in zip(filenames, labels):
                true_label = image_labels.merge(pd.DataFrame({"ImageId":[filename[:-4]]}), on="ImageId")["TrueLabel"][0]
                predictions.append([filename[:-4], true_label, label])
```

---

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-307b2daa19e5> in <module>
     88 
     89 
---> 90     with tf.train.MonitoredSession(session_creator=session_creator) as sess:
     91         for filenames, images in load_images(FLAGS.input_dir, batch_shape):
     92             labels = sess.run(predicted_labels, feed_dict={x_input: images})

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py in __init__(self, session_creator, hooks, stop_grace_period_secs)
   1005         hooks,
   1006         should_recover=True,
-> 1007         stop_grace_period_secs=stop_grace_period_secs)
   1008 
   1009 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py in __init__(self, session_creator, hooks, should_recover, stop_grace_period_secs)
    723         stop_grace_period_secs=stop_grace_period_secs)
    724     if should_recover:
--> 725       self._sess = _RecoverableSession(self._coordinated_creator)
    726     else:
    727       self._sess = self._coordinated_creator.create_session()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py in __init__(self, sess_creator)
   1198     """
   1199     self._sess_creator = sess_creator
-> 1200     _WrappedSession.__init__(self, self._create_session())
   1201 
   1202   def _create_session(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py in _create_session(self)
   1203     while True:
   1204       try:
-> 1205         return self._sess_creator.create_session()
   1206       except _PREEMPTION_ERRORS as e:
   1207         logging.info(

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py in create_session(self)
    869       """Creates a coordinated session."""
    870       # Keep the tf_sess for unit testing.
--> 871       self.tf_sess = self._session_creator.create_session()
    872       # We don't want coordinator to suppress any exception.
    873       self.coord = coordinator.Coordinator(clean_stop_exception_types=[])

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py in create_session(self)
    636 
    637   def create_session(self):
--> 638     self._scaffold.finalize()
    639     return self._get_session_manager().prepare_session(
    640         self._master,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py in finalize(self)
    238 
    239     ops.get_default_graph().finalize()
--> 240     logging.info('Graph was finalized.')
    241     return self
    242 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\tf_logging.py in info(msg, *args, **kwargs)
    154 @tf_export(v1=['logging.info'])
    155 def info(msg, *args, **kwargs):
--> 156   get_logger().info(msg, *args, **kwargs)
    157 
    158 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py in info(self, msg, *args, **kwargs)
   1306         """
   1307         if self.isEnabledFor(INFO):
-> 1308             self._log(INFO, msg, args, **kwargs)
   1309 
   1310     def warning(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py in _log(self, level, msg, args, exc_info, extra, stack_info)
   1442         record = self.makeRecord(self.name, level, fn, lno, msg, args,
   1443                                  exc_info, func, extra, sinfo)
-> 1444         self.handle(record)
   1445 
   1446     def handle(self, record):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py in handle(self, record)
   1452         """
   1453         if (not self.disabled) and self.filter(record):
-> 1454             self.callHandlers(record)
   1455 
   1456     def addHandler(self, hdlr):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py in callHandlers(self, record)
   1514                 found = found + 1
   1515                 if record.levelno >= hdlr.level:
-> 1516                     hdlr.handle(record)
   1517             if not c.propagate:
   1518                 c = None    #break out

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\absl\logging\__init__.py in handle(self, record)
    889     rv = self.filter(record)
    890     if rv:
--> 891       return self._current_handler.handle(record)
    892     return rv
    893 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py in handle(self, record)
    863             self.acquire()
    864             try:
--> 865                 self.emit(record)
    866             finally:
    867                 self.release()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\absl\logging\__init__.py in emit(self, record)
    824         _warn_preinit_stderr = False
    825       self._log_to_stderr(record)
--> 826     elif FLAGS['logtostderr'].value:
    827       self._log_to_stderr(record)
    828     else:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\absl\flags\_flagvalues.py in __getitem__(self, name)
    461   def __getitem__(self, name):
    462     """Returns the Flag object for the flag --name."""
--> 463     return self._flags()[name]
    464 
    465   def _hide_flag(self, name):

KeyError: 'logtostderr'
```